# jQuery fullpage js fix my CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am not able to fix my CSS in http://albertoramacciotti.me
The word Obert is not in the middle and not in the center of the section.
Without Javascript is working fine: http://albertoramacciotti.me/without-JS/
It's about those wrapper divs created by the plugin that are destroying my page.
Someone could try to help me, please?

Comment: share your code here

Comment: why you don't use display: flex property. It is the most easy solution for vertical centering. Display: table vertical centering is very old and also bad way https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The accepted solution is not the correct one. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see - your javascript is adding a div (.fp-tableCell) within your section to assign it a height which breaks your table styling set in section and table-cell styling in your div.content.

What you can do in your CSS is to assign

```
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This would fix your problem that you have right now - but if all you are trying to do is create a full page container - I would look into using flex box or maybe even just use `height:100vh;` to force the section to be page height.

Comment: I do believe @Alvaro 's answer is more correct, after all, it is their plugin. My css class is actually fixes this specific issue but including the plugin's css could fix a number of other hidden issues.

Line 53 to 58 in [`jquery.fullpage.css`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.css#L53) shows the same fix

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the fullpagel.js css file [`jquery.fullpage.css`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.css)

As detailed [in the fullpage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#usage):

> As you can see in the example files, you will need to include:
>
> - jQuery library. (1.6.0 minimum)
> - The JavaScript file jquery.fullPage.js (or its minified version jquery.fullPage.min.js)
> - **The css file jquery.fullPage.css**

Comment: Have or not the CSS fullpage file is irrilevant: it no works still with the CSS

Comment: The solution you accepted is just adding part of the missing CSS that the fullpage CSS adds... My solution is the correct one...

Comment: Having the CSS enabled and no .fp-tableCell in my .css doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: `.fp-tableCell ` is already defined in the fullpage.js css file... [Just take a look at it and check if for yourself](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.css#L53) if you dont believe me...

Comment: I meant that it no works if I add just the jquery.fullpage.css I believe in you